# How to test exception with @WebfluxTest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-webflux, spring-boot-test

I am trying to test exception path for my controller with `@WebfluxTest`, but it is always throws a server exception and then return a 500 error.

The test codes is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/server/src/test/java/com/example/demo/PostControllerTest.java#L112-L123):

```
@Test
@Ignore // ignore it temporarily 
public void getPostByNonExistedId_shouldReturn404() {
    given(posts.findById("1"))
        .willReturn(Mono.empty());

    client.get().uri("/posts/1").exchange()
        .expectStatus().isNotFound();

    verify(this.posts, times(1)).findById(anyString());
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(this.posts);
}
```

The controller codes is:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public Mono<Post> get(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    return this.posts.findById(id).switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new PostNotFoundException(id)));
}
```

The `PostNotFoundException` is caught in the background correctly, but it is not handled by my custom `RestExceptionHandler` in my `@WebfluxTest` test.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @Krotz I think this should be a bug, the traditional mvc test works well.

Answer (score 3):

For the future audience for this question, this question was raised as [an issue against the Spring Boot issue tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13627#event-1811823511) by the author of the question and has been resolved via adding support for `WebExceptionHandler` in `@WebFluxTest`, so the code in question should just work since [the Spring Boot 2.1.0.M3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/milestone/117) which is not released yet at the time of writing.