# SpringBootTest - Test exception when request is invalid

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, kotlin, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I developed an API using web-flux which is working fine when I make request using POSTMAN. My code is:

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/post", produces = ["application/xml"])
fun post(@Valid request: RequestData): Mono<Response> {
    return Mono.just(request)
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

dto:

```
data class RequestData(

    @get:NotBlank
    @get:Email
    val email: String = "",
)
```

So whenever I pass invalid email via POSTMAN, I'm catching the exception like below and its working:

```
@ExceptionHandler
fun bindingExceptionHandler(e: WebExchangeBindException) = "Custom Error Message"
```

But now when I write UT(@WebFluxTest) for this case (Invalid emaid), It failed.

```
@Test
fun testWhenInvalidEmail() {

    // Request body
    val email = "invalidemail"
    val request = LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>()
    request.add("email", email)

    webTestClient.post().uri("/post")
        .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(request))
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus().isOk
}
```

When I debug this, I found that my exceptionHandler not coming into picture when request coming through unit test. I'm using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type in POST request.

Please let me know where I'm doing wrong. 
[I followed this question as well but didn't work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48162730/how-to-test-exception-with-webfluxtest)

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.0.6 `id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.6.RELEASE'`

Comment: The question you’re pointing to says it’s been fixed in 2.1.x

Comment: Now I updated spring boot version to 2.1.0 but still facing same issue.

Comment: My bad. I missed to add `.controllerAdvice(ExceptionsHandler())` in webTestClient builder. It worked now. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on another related question, this has been fixed in Spring Boot 2.1.0.

Also, you shouldn't have to build `WebTestClient` yourself but instead inject it in your test class ([see reference documentation about that](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-webflux-tests)):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebFluxTest(MyValidationController.class)
public class MyValidationControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webClient;

    @Test
    public void testWhenInvalidEmail() {
        //...
    }

}
```